# Ошибка в entity framework "Unable to determine the relationship.."

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Пытаюсь создать и заполнить базу данных, но на моменте создания базы вылетает ошибка "Unable to determine the relationship presented by navigation 'Movie.Actors' of type 'HashSet< Person>'". Что не так с Hashet< Person>? Какая-то ошибка в many-to-many relationships? Буду рад любой помощи.

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public HashSet<Movie> ActorMovies { get; set; }

        public Person() { }

        public Person(string id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
```

```
public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Rating { get; set; }
        public HashSet<Person> Actors { get; set; }
        public Person Director { get; set; }
        public HashSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        public Movie() { }

        public Movie(string id, string name, double rating, HashSet<Person> actors, Person director, HashSet<Tag> tags)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Rating = rating;
            Actors = actors;
            Director = director;
            Tags = tags;
        }
    }
```

```
class ApplicationContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        public ApplicationContext()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Movies;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
```